# It's still crashing, where am I going wrong?

Tags: c

*(Edited to add this bit)* I'm writing a program where it reads in a string of characters, then counts the frequency of each letter in the string and outputs the number of times each letter or non-letter occurs.

I was using tolower() but this was creating a problem.

I've changed it so I'm now using a loop to lower the case. Unfortunately the program is still crashing on me and I can't spot the problem.

I've run through each function to make sure I don't have anything loose. I've got the new line element being removed but when I run it through, I type in something as simple as "hello" and it crashes out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void read(char letterfreq[], int STRSIZE)
{
    printf("The capacity of the string array is %d\n", STRSIZE-1);

    printf("Please enter your string:\n");

    letterfreq[strlen(letterfreq) - 1] = '\0';

    return;
}

void lowerCase(char letterfreq[], int STRSIZE)
{
    }


}

void countFreq(int counter[], int COUNT, char letterfreq[], int STRSIZE)
{
    int c = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < STRSIZE; i++)

            }
            else 
                if((letterfreq[i] < 'a') || (letterfreq[i] > 'z'))
                {   
                    counter[COUNT-1]++;
                }
        }
    }

    return;
}

void printFreq(int counter[], int COUNT)
{
    int c;

    printf("Here is the letter frequency of your string:\n");

    for(c = 0; c < COUNT; c++)

    printf("There were also %d special characters in the string.\n", counter[26]);

    return;
}

char promptReset(char reset)
{
    printf("Would you like to calculate the letter frequency of another string? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%c%*c", &reset);


    do
    {
        readString(letterfreq, STRSIZE);

        lowerCase(letterfreq, STRSIZE);

        countFreq(counter, COUNT, letterfreq, STRSIZE);

        printFreq(counter, COUNT);

        reset = promptReset(reset);

    }while(reset == 'y' || 'Y');

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post the question as a continuation of another question, because many users might not know about your previous question.

Comment: This is wrong `reset == 'y' || 'Y'`, it should be `reset == 'y' || reset == 'Y'`, it's always evaluating to true as it is. And `return` is not a function!

Comment: Run in a debugger to locate the crash. When the crash happens and you have gone up the call stack to your code (if needed) take a look at all involved variables, make sure all pointers and indexes are valid. At the very least, please point out where the crash happens in your code.

Comment: `letterfreq[i] = letterfreq[i] - 32;` does not lowercase it. You need `letterfreq[i] = letterfreq[i] + 'a' - 'A'`;. Another fault with `lowerCase()` is you are incrementing `i` twice. Once in the `for` statement, again at the end of the loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I agree with you stylistically, but `'a' - 'A' == 32` on any machine with a character set congruent with ASCII.  If you don't want to assume ASCII congruence then adding `'a' - 'A'` is not a safe mechanism for lowercasing letters other than `'A'`, as nothing requires the spacing between equivalent lower- and uppercase letters to be consistent.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I put that to stave off the usual cries of "oh someone will be using EBCDIC". But although EBCDIC has consistent upper to lower difference, testing the range A to Z will fail.

Comment: there is a standard function `tolower()`which you can use to get the lowercase char.

Answer (score 4):

Here(in function `lowerCase`):

```
letterfreq[i] = letterfreq[i] - 32;
```

you need to *add* 32 to convert the character into uppercase. Look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) to know why.

Here(in function `countFreq`):

```
for(i = 0; i < STRSIZE; i++)
{   
    while(letterfreq[i] != '\0')
    {   
        if(letterfreq[i] >= 'a' && letterfreq[i] <= 'z')
        {
            counter[c]++;
            c++;
        }
        else 
            if((letterfreq[i] < 'a') || (letterfreq[i] > 'z'))
            {   
                counter[COUNT-1]++;
            }
    }
}
```

the `for` loop doesn't make any sense. Remove it. Then, the `while` loop never ends as you don't increment `i`. You need `i++;` at the end of the `while` loop.

Here:

```
        if(letterfreq[i] >= 'a' && letterfreq[i] <= 'z')
        {
            counter[c]++;
            c++;
        }
```

`counter[c]++` won't count the frequency of each character. You need

```
counter[letterfreq[i]-'a']++;
```

for that. `c` is not needed. Remove it from the function.

---

Also, as [@iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob) [has mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214537/its-still-crashing-where-am-i-going-wrong/30214785#comment48533162_30214537),

```
 }while(reset == 'y' || 'Y');
```

should be

```
 }while(reset == 'y' || reset == 'Y');
```

---

Fixed program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const int COUNT = 27;
const int STRSIZE = 100;

void readString(char letterfreq[], int STRSIZE)
{
    printf("The capacity of the string array is %d\n", STRSIZE-1);

    printf("Please enter your string:\n");
    fgets(letterfreq, STRSIZE, stdin);

    letterfreq[strlen(letterfreq) - 1] = '\0';

    //return; Not required
}

void lowerCase(char letterfreq[], int STRSIZE)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < STRSIZE; i++)
    {
        if(letterfreq[i] >= 'A' && letterfreq[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            letterfreq[i] = letterfreq[i] + 32; //Add instead of subtract
        }
        //i++; You already increment i from the loop
    }


}

void countFreq(int counter[], int COUNT, char letterfreq[], int STRSIZE)
{
    int i=0; // You forgot to initialize i with 0

    while(letterfreq[i] != '\0')
    {   
        if(letterfreq[i] >= 'a' && letterfreq[i] <= 'z')
        {
            counter[letterfreq[i]-'a']++;
        }
        else if((letterfreq[i] < 'a') || (letterfreq[i] > 'z')) //is always true; Use `else`
        {   
            counter[COUNT-1]++;
        }

        i++; //You forgot this
    }

    //return; Not required
}

void printFreq(int counter[], int COUNT)
{
    int c;

    printf("Here is the letter frequency of your string:\n");

    for(c = 0; c < COUNT-1; c++) //See change here too
    {
        printf("%c \t %d \n", c + 'a', counter[c]);
    }

    printf("There were also %d special characters in the string.\n", counter[26]);

    //return; Not required
}

char promptReset(char reset)
{
    printf("Would you like to calculate the letter frequency of another string? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%c%*c", &reset);

    return(reset);
}

int main()
{
    char letterfreq[STRSIZE];
    char reset = '\0'; //Always initialize variables to prevent unexpected behavior
    int counter[COUNT];


    printf("Welcome to the Letter Frequency program\n");

    do
    {
        memset(counter,0,sizeof(counter)); //Initializing counter with zeros
        memset(letterfreq,'\0',sizeof(letterfreq)); //Do the same for letterfreq

        readString(letterfreq, STRSIZE);

        lowerCase(letterfreq, STRSIZE);

        countFreq(counter, COUNT, letterfreq, STRSIZE);

        printFreq(counter, COUNT);

        reset = promptReset(reset);

    }while(reset == 'y' || reset == 'Y'); //Changed

    return(0);
}
```